# Ruby on Rails gmail does not display email images

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, gmail

When my rails app sends email with image to gmail address - gmail does not display that image
At the beginning I had image tag in my html email code:

```
 <img alt="" src="http://my_image/url/email_logo.svg" style="width: 200px; height: 40%;" />
```

But gmail does not display this image when I viewing it in the browser, but image displays if I viewing same email by using email client (AirMail)
I changed this image to inline attachment:

email view:

```
<td valign="bottom"><%= image_tag  attachments['email_logo.svg'].url , alt: '', style: "width: 200px; height: 40%;" -%></td>
```

my_mailer.rb

```
def send_my_email(email)
    @email = email
    attachments.inline['email_logo.svg'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/", "email_logo.svg"))
    mail(to: @email, subject: 'My Email')
  end
```

How to make gmail to display this image?

Comment: can you check if `send_my_email.html.erb` is being rendered or not ?

Comment: This error I getting when rails executing code from send_my_email.html.erb

Comment: show the log please..

Comment: just added log, look for this file `send_report_email.html.erb in the` log

Comment: From your logs, it seems the attachment is not being created. My first guess is that it may be a media error. Try doing this:

``File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/", "email_logo.svg"), mime_type: 'image/svg+xml')``

Comment: first issue is gone, it was my mistake had 2 files attached to the email, after removing one file - error gone

Comment: Just still gmail does not  display this image! Why? It displays in yahoo mails with no problems

Answer (score 4):

I read in another post on SO that Gmail straight-up does not support SVG.  You need to switch to png or jpg